# Get likes of venues from user's friends

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is it possible with [the new Facebook Graphi API 2.5](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2015/10/07/graph-api-v2.5/) to check how many friends (just a number, no names etc.) of a user liked a certain venue (restaurant, museum, etc.)?

I checked the Graph API explorer and there is the following debug message:

```
Only friends who installed this app are returned in API v2.0 and higher.
total_count in summary represents the total number of friends,
including those who haven't installed the app.
```

Is it possible?

Comment: _“Is the total_count related to the number of friends a user has or the likes of the friends?”_ – what endpoint you are requesting data from here? If it is `/me/friends`, then of course it is the number of friends, because that endpoint has nothing whatsoever to do with any “likes”.

Comment: Not possible... there's no endpoint that will achieve this